# php save html-code in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a little problem to save html-code in phpmyadmin.

Thats the html-code (`$html_txt`) which I would like to save in the sql-table. I get the code from an other sql-query.

```
An g&uuml;nstigen Tagen "Paradies" ist es dienlich.
Test/Test<br /><br />"Test"
```

And that is my query.

```
$id = 1;
$html = "'".$html_txt"'";
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET text = '.$html_txt.' WHERE id = '.$id.'';
```

That does not work. Any idea? I tried it also like this:

```
$id = 1;
$html_txt;
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET text = '.$html_txt.' WHERE id = '.$id.'';
```

Comment: You seem confused as to what PHPMyadmin is - this is an application written by someone else for accessing a MySQL database which /happens/ to be written in PHP - how it works/behaves has little or nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape the string statements before querying. Your query should be like the following:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db");
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $id);
$html_txt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $html_txt); 
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET text = ' . $html_txt . ' WHERE id = ' . $id . '';
```

I die if I do not say:

1. Please use parameterized query
2. Please avoid using vulnerable sql statements.

Comment: It is interessting: If I put the query manually direct in phpMyAdmin --> SQL it change e.g. the value 100'000 to 100''000

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_escape_string` to support for `html entities` and may the text be the kwyword so use like this text

```
$id = 1;
$html =mysql_real_escape_string($html_txt);
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET `text` = '.$html.' WHERE id = '.$id.'';
```

Comment: mysql_escape_string does not work. "Deprecated: mysql_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string.php]: This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead." I tried also mysql_real_escape_string, but it does not work, too.

Comment: @yab86 `mysql_` functions are deprecated (means, you should not use them, they'll get removed from PHP anyways), best solution yet from Africa Matjie.

Comment: I have it: `text = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($html_txt).'\'`

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment - but it's a bit verbose.

It should be obvious to most PHP developers that the problem is lack of escaping of the HTML string, however that in itself is not a reason for this being a poor question.

You've not provided details of any attempt to investigate the problem yourself. "Doesn't work" is not a good description of what happenned - in this case the expected outcome is fairly obvious to me, but that's not always the case. I aslo know what the actual outcome would be - but you've not documented that either. In most occassions where code does not behave as expected, an error message will be reported somewhere - you should be looking for it. The DBMS would have returned a specific error message - which your code should poll - especially if you are running into problems.

If you had viewed the SQL you were sending (or included it in your post) this would also have helped diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly escape your HTML value. Though this solution is not optimal as it does not use parameterized queries (PDO, ....), try this:

```
$html = 'An g&uuml;nstigen Tagen "Paradies" ist es dienlich. Test/Test<br /><br />"Test"';
$id = 1;
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET text = '.mysql_real_escape_string($html).' WHERE id = '.$id.'';
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use mySQli prepared statement, WHY : i think somewhere along the line your variable have funny characters that r messing up with your query..with prepared statements the query is send alone then after your variables are binded to it, pls check above code

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "your username", "your pass", "your db");
$myString = "Your string here";
$id  = 1;

$insertDB = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET text = ? WHERE id = ?");
$insertDB->bind_param('si', $myString, $id); //bind data, type string and int 'si'
$insertDB->execute(); //execute your query
$conn->close(); //close connection
```

Comment: Although the issue is the represenation of the data, understanding and implementing this properly is not an optional way of addressing a specific functional issue - it is fundamental to developing reliable and secure code.